# Creating docker containers on Windows

Tags: vagrant, docker, boot2docker, fig

So getting boot2docker up and running, and pulling containers from the Docker Hub are non-issue on a windows environment. But if I wish to create a container and run it, how do I go about doing this? I've read about using fig, but is fig installed via Windows or from the container? I've attempted to do it from the container, but it often results in a permissions error, and even CHOWNing the folder doesn't solve the issue of not being able to call fig in the container.

Is it even possible to just run docker via Boot2Docker on windows as a development environment? Or should I just use Vagrant as the host VM and play with a bunch of docker containers in it?

Just some clarification and direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fig is a tool for working with Docker. It runs on the host (which could mean your Windows host communicating with Docker via the TCP socket, or could mean your boot2docker VM which is a guest of your windows machine and a host of your Docker containers).

All that Fig's doing is streamlining the process of pulling, building and starting Docker images.  For example, this fig.yml

```
db:
 image: postgres
app:
 build: .
 links:
  - "db:db"
 environment:
  - FOO=bar
```

is (roughly) the same as this series of Docker commands in Bash:

```
docker run -d --name db postgres
docker build -t app .
docker run -d --name app --link=db:db --env=FOO=bar app
```

Comment: I thought all of the docker tools for windows ran in a thin Linux VM in VirtualBox.  VB was part of the install last time I looked.

Comment: I don't know Windows. I just can't think of a reason that the Docker client couldn't run on Windows (it's just a REST client), just like the client runs on the Mac even though the server requires a Linux machine.

Comment: Well, considering that currently there is no "official" docker support for windows aside from boot2docker, trying to get things like a Yii2 dev environment locally on a windows machine is a pain in the rump. Fig is incompatible, and even taking a crack at phundament/app with just docker has also been a hassle. honestly, I'm looking for a way to set this up and if needed, be taught or instructed.

Comment: currently I am trying a vagrant Vm with docker containers and just using docker natively inside vagrant.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot It didn't exactly answer my question, but thanks for helping. I ended up just running it the app in Vagrant with its ports forwarded.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Thanks for posting a follow-up.