# Having trouble creating Lambda Layer using Docker on Windows

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have been trying to create a python-based Lambda Layer using Docker Desktop on Windows. Specifically, I am trying to have a single Lambda Layer that includes the packages Pyomo, Ipopt, Cython.

I've been able to successfully create a Lambda Layer for Pyomo, but not been able to include Ipopt or Cython, when I spun up an Amazon Linux EC2 instance, but since I am majority on a Windows machine, I'm really trying to figure out the best way to create these Lambda layers.

[Unable to create AWS Lambda Deployment Package for ipopt, pyomo, cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295282/unable-to-create-aws-lambda-deployment-package-for-ipopt-pyomo-cython) << this question ~90% there, but just missing how to do it on Docker for Windows?

Below are the below resources I've researched:

[Creating docker containers on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052753/creating-docker-containers-on-windows)
[docker inside docker on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568035/docker-inside-docker-on-windows)
[Creating docker containers on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052753/creating-docker-containers-on-windows)
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/creating-a-lambda-layer-via-docker-python-layers-docker-e4e318717822
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Comment: Can you use linux machine on aws or in virtual box?

Comment: Previously, I was using Amazon Linix AMI  on AWS EC2.  I can't use either now on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: I see. Sadly I don't know how to do it on Windows. I could only check for linux.